# Get back to Android activity after background thread is complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parsing, user-interface

I'm using Parse with my Android app, and my code looks like this:

```
public class SignupActivity extends Activity {
//Collect signup data
User.signupInBackground(data);
}



public class User{
//User methods, constructors, etc
public static void signup(data){
ParseUser pUser = new ParseUser();
//Build data into pUser
pUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e){
            if (e!=null){
                Log.v("Signup",e.toString());
            }
        }

    });
```

So the question is, how do I notify my activity when the signUpInBackground process is complete? I can't have SignupActivity implement SignUpCallback because it's an abstract class and I have to extend Activity.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is display a dialog box or waiting animation, and then get rid of it when the background thread is done. Alternatively, the background thread could launch an activity. The problem with this is that the User class and the anonymous inner class don't have their own Context, so they can't start activities.

I'm fairly new at this, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several approaches might work given your current code structure.

1. Create a `Handler` in `SignupActivity` and pass that to the `User` so it has a way of interacting with the activity.
2. Make `SignUpCallback` an interface instead of an abstract class.
3. Create an instance of a concreate subclass of `SignUpCallback` in your `SignupActivity` class; it will have access to the methods of `SignupActivity`.

I'm assuming that `signUpInBackground` is executing on a worker thread and that the callback is invoked from that thread. If that's correct, then in all cases you will need to interact with `SignupActivity` through a `Handler`. Thus, I'd suggest method #1 unless the other approaches allow for cleaner code.

Comment: signUpInBackground runs on a worker thread, and then calls the done() function on the UI thread

Comment: @Cyclic - In that case, just pass a reference to the `SignupActivity` to the `User` object and use that to call back into the activity from within `done()`, or pass a `Handler` and have `done` post a message.

Comment: I ended up passing a Handler...the way I did it was then declaring a local variable as final inside the signup() method and setting that final variable to the handler I passed in. I then used the local handler variable in the anonymous function.

Is this the right way to use passed-in parameters in an anonymous function within a class method? Or is there something better? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Cyclic - That method sounds as good as any. The main thing to stay away from is keeping Activity-related values (like a Handler) in static variables. Those can cause memory leaks if an activity is destroyed and recreated (if, say, the user rotates the device).